# QGIS 'Join attributes by location' algorithm (sometimes?) not working properly in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-modeler

In QGIS 2.14.10 I've set up a simple model to assign `min` and `max` of attributes of a point layer (`adresses`, about 2500 features) to a polygon layer (`parcels`, about 14000 features) to polygons containing the points (hint: polygons were created with polygonize algorithm, so these should have valid topology):

[image]

The 'Join attributes by location' algorithm is set up like this:

[image]

The resulting `bla` polygon layer is created, but has zero features:

[image]

After some playing around, I found that turning of *on-the-fly-projection* solved my issue ...

[image]

... but unfortunatly not for long. So toggeling *on-the-fly-projection* sometimes helps, but the behaviour of 'Join attributes by location' algorithm does not seem to depend on whether OTF projection is ON or OFF and is, furthermore, unpredictable when toggling OTF projection.

Am I missing something in modeler, or is there any advice of using this algorithm in the context of OTF projection?

Comment: Is the CRS of the output layer the same as the input layers?

Comment: yep, both epsg:31468

Comment: Does it work all the time outside the modeler?

Comment: as far as i can see until now, yes.

Comment: Because your are dealing with points and polygons, I suggest you using the "intersects" predicate (because it is faster and it could probably solve your problem).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a **custom script** into your modeler instead of calling the tool directly and see if it makes a difference:

```
##Join_attributes_by_location=name
##Layer_1=vector
##Layer_2=vector
##Output=output vector

layer_1 = processing.getObject(Layer_1)
layer_2 = processing.getObject(Layer_2)

processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", layer_1, layer_2, u'contains', 0, 1, 'min,max', 0, Output)
```